# IntelliJ - Cucumber step definition case

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-java

Ever since I upgraded to latest community edition of IntelliJ 15.0.3, whenever I auto generate a step definition from the feature definition file using `alt + enter`, it creates the method in camel case rather than usual style with underscores.

For e.g. it used to be generated like this

```
@When("Cucumber is awesome")
public void cucumber_is_awesome() {}
```

But now it generates in usual camelCase convention:

```
@When("Cucumber is awesome")
public void cucumberIsAwesome() {}
```

Is there any way to change this setting back to the first style?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is check the

> Run -> Edit Configuration

then go to the cucumber config. Within the Program Arguments check if

> --snippets camelcase

is present and take it out. that should make it show it in snake casing again. Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Alternatively, you could explicitly add the argument to get snippets the preferred way (use argument --help to get the different options)

Comment: I don't see a config file. What can I do now?

Comment: @paul, might be late already but, it's not a configuration file but the Intellij Run Menu setting.