# Trying to upgrade from Cucumber 1.0.2 info.cukes to 5.6 io.cucumber, step definition not being recognized

Tags: java, java-8, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to upgrade the suite from old info.cukes (1.0.2) to io.cucumber (5.6) with latest version.

The step definitions are recognized with the old imports but as soon as I change the import and remove the old dependencies, step definitions are not recognized.

Can anyone suggest the best way to upgrade. We are in desperate need to use the new features not available in old version.

unfortunately due to policy i can not add any snippets.

Comment: Where is the message showing up? on the feature file in the IDE?

Comment: Yes. we are using intelllij and it is not able to recognize the step definitions. when trying to run, it throws step not defined exception.

Comment: for the intellij part this could help u - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57416690/undefined-step-reference-intellij-java. Lot of things have changed since version 1. U could try using dryRun option of runner to generate step definitions and check if these are found.