# Create step definitions with underscore in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber

I was going through this post [IntelliJ - Cucumber step definition case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35646605/intellij-cucumber-step-definition-case)

But I don't see cucumber config in IntelliJ community edition version 11.0.8.

[image]

I already have Cucumber Java plugin installed.

[image]

Restarted IntelliJ after adding `--snippets underscore` but it is still giving camelcase.

[image]

So how can I get underscore instead of camelcase?

Comment: `But I don't see cucumber config in IntelliJ community edition version 11.0.8.` Check that the Cucumber plugin is installed in IDE.

Answer (score 1):

To get underscore instead of camel case add the below properties in your `junit-platform.properties` . If this file does not exist , you can create and place it in `src/test/resources` . Junit5 will detect it automatically and run based on configs provided in that file. For junit5 , we should be using this in pom [`cucumber-junit-platform-engine`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/junit-platform-engine/README.md)

```
cucumber.plugin = summary
cucumber.snippet-type=underscore
cucumber.execution.dry-run= true
```

For a scenario like this in feature file

```
Given I log this <TestTest>
```

When you build  project in intellij , cucumber will generate this on console. You can copy this in stepdefs

```
@Given("I log this {string}")
public void i_log_this(String string) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
```

If you are using junit 4 you have to use corresponding options in your

`@RunWith(Cucumber.class)`

You can find related information on this [cucumber docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/)

Comment: Where I can find `junit-platform.properties`. I am using mac.